# Model Binding doesn't work with System.Drawing objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I would like to pass a picture settings from page to controller. I pass data through JSON. I have JS object like below:

```
    var fields = this.props.settings;
    var settings = {
        ID: fields.id,
        Title: fields.title,
        Size: {
            Width: fields.size.width,
            Height: fields.size.height
        },
        SizeType: fields.sizeType,
        MimeType: {
            ID: fields.id,
            Title: fields.title,
            Extension: fields.ext
        }};
```

I send data by AJAX:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify({ settings: settings }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (message) {
            self.refs.progress.onSuccess(message);
        },
        error: function (message) {
            self.refs.progress.onFailed("Ups... something wrong :(");
        }
    });
```

My controller looks like:

```
    public ActionResult ConvertPictures(ConvertSettings settings)
```

My model looks like below:

```
public class ConvertSettings : IListItem
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }  //OK

    public string Title { get; set; } //OK

    public System.Drawing.Size Size { get; set; } //NOK 

    public SizeType SizeType { get; set; } //OK

    public MimeType MimeType { get; set; } //OK
}
```

I have problem problem with 'Size' property. Controller receive 'Size' property
with:

```
{Height = 0, Width = 0}
```

I've tried also with Rectangle class but there is the same problem. I parsed JSON values to int:

```
Size: {
        Width: 123,
        Height: 33
    }
```

But still in controller, model has {Height = 0, Width = 0}. Other properties (ID, enums etc.) work good. I use DefaultModelBinder in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Size Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a parameterless constructor, so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize it and set its values.

Create you own class to receive and bind the values (and using the `System.Drawing` namespace is not appropriate in a mvc app anyway), for example

```
public class ImageSize
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set }
}
```

and change the `ConvertSettings` to use it

to

```
public class ConvertSettings : IListItem
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public ImageSize Size { get; set; }
    ....
}
```